# Printing sprintf without quotes

Tags: r

I have some IDs that I want to eventually loop into a larger variable:

```
playerId <- c(12345, 23456, 34567)
```

But to first do that, I need to use `sprintf` to create the necessary lines of code that will run correctly in an API request that looks like something like this when I'm running one at a time:

```
    POST(
  'https://api.secure.com/v1/Test',
  accept_json(),                       
  content_type_json(),                  
  add_headers(Authorization = VanAPI),  
  encode = "json",
  body=list(playerId = 12345)
)
```

When I run the above request, it works just fine. But for the purposes of a loop, I want it to look like this:

```
POST(
  'https://api.secure.com/v1/Test',
  accept_json(),                       
  content_type_json(),                  
  add_headers(Authorization = ApiKey),  
  encode = "json",
  PlayerIdLines
)
```

So what I'm doing is creating a series of the necessary line I need for each ID:

```
PlayerIdLines <- cat(sprintf('body=list(playerId = %s\n)', playerId))
```

When I first run that line, it produces this output:

```
> PlayerIdLines <- cat(sprintf('body=list(playerId = %s\n)', playerId)) 
body=list(targetId = 12345
) body=list(targetId = 23456
) body=list(targetId = 34567
)
```

But then after that, whenever I try to execute variable `PlayerIdLines`, all it does is return `null`:

```
> PlayerIdLines
NULL
```

Why is that happening? Why is it being stored as `NULL`?

**EDIT: BASED ON MR FLICK'S ANSWER**

I try running the following:

```
get_data <- function(url) {

POST(
  'https://api.secure.com/v1/Test',
  accept_json(),                       
  content_type_json(),                  
  add_headers(Authorization = VanAPI),  
  encode = "json",
  body=list(playerId = playerId)
)

}

map_df(playerIds, get_data, .id = 'log') -> CreateDF
```

But I'm met with the following error:

```
Error: Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
```

Comment: You can't build parameters as stings. If you are looping, use `body=list(playerId = playerId)` in the code. (assuming `playerId` is a variable with only one value at a time.) If you want to make multiple calls to the endpoint, you'll need to call `POST()` separately for each one.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! See the edit I just made because I'm running running into a new issue

Comment: Your function `get_data` has a parameter `url` that you are not using. You seem to use the same URL but the player ID changes each time. So use `get_data <- function(playerId) { ... }` instead since that's the variable that's changing. It's also unlikely that POST is returning a data.frame so `map_df` is probably not a good choice unless you parse the contents of the results. Try just a regular `map()` instead.